# Azure VM DNS - What to specify as 'NS' and 'A' record

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have created virtual machine in Azure with static IP. I specified a DNS Name in my ResourceGroup called **somevm**. So Azure automatically made it **somevm.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com**

Then I added endpoint on public port 80, so the website can be accessed via localhost, via http:// ipaddress/ (outside of VM) and http://somevm.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com

On my existing hosting provider, I see the following DNS entries.

```
NS ns1.myhost.arvixevps.com    
NS ns2.myhost.arvixevps.com    
A <ipaddress>    
* A <ipaddress>    
www A <ipaddress>    
mail A <ipaddress>    
mail2 A <ipaddress>    
MX [10], mail.mywebsite.com    
MX [21], mail2.mywebsite.com    
TXT globalsign-domain-verification=SKFHKSJHDLKUERIJKDCFJLKF_234KJFDJK
```

I want to migrate my website from Existing hosting to the Azure VM.

What do I need to enter in NS, and 'A' records. Do I also need to enter CNAME? If yes, what will it be and how to find it for my Azure VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need to be able to configure your domain for Azure Virtual Machine is [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name-portal/) including CNAME/A records difference and what do you need to put on your domain registrar site. The reason that i added the link for the Cloud Service is that virtual machines in a classic mode (if you created that VM) reside in the specific entity called Cloud Service.

If you created the new Azure VM, then you could go with the [Azure DNS service](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/moving-to-azure-dns/) or [that](http://www.seesharprun.net/arm_custom_domain_vm/) approach.

So, CNAME is basically the alias for the azure domain, and you may see the first domain. With A, the domain maps to the IP address of the resource instead of the domain. The choice depends on your scenario. The simplest way is to configure CNAME because if you configure A, you will need to configure static IP (or, because of the dynamic nature of a cloud, it may change in a future, so you will need to change it on your domain registrar site).

Some useful links for understanding how things are working here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/dns-domain-delegation/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/dns-operations-recordsets/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cloud_solution_architect/archive/2015/05/05/creating-azure-vms-with-arm-powershell-cmdlets.aspx

Comment: Thanks Alex for your response but I do not have a Azure WebApp. I have a Azure VM. In my case, what does these records point to?

Comment: Yes, i noticed too late, sorry. Changed the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the new Azure portal. Since I have a Azure VM, can you tell me how to find the CNAME records? From the link you shared, it says I have to find a site url. But I do not have a site url on my GUI. Also in my case, should my 'NS' be pointed to somevm.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com?

Comment: *.cloudapp.* is your domain name that is bound to the IP address for the VM. Domain name will change only if you will do this. IP address will change if you will not set up the reserved ip. CNAME is the record that maps your mywebsite.com to the different domain (not ip) and acts as an alias. A is the record that maps your mywebsite.com to the IP. So, CNAME will be website.com => *cloudapp* => IP, and A will be website.com => IP. In both of cases, you do not need NS record, you just need to set up A or CNAME

Comment: Domain delegation link i included says about NS record, and it is important information, but only if you need DNS delegation. From your question, i do not see that you do. Or, if you are sure that you need that, then see the "Delegating a domain to Azure DNS" section.

Comment: Wow I never knew I could skip 'NS' altogether. In my DNS Naming, I currently have NS set to ns1.myhost.arvixevps.com and ns2.myhost.arvixevps.com . Do I delete these NS records or do I keep them blank. In the past 2 days, this is probably the first instance when I feel I am moving forward and understanding things. Thanks so much.

Comment: I tried to understand how Arvixe is working, it looks like they have standard procedures. Please try what was proposed in the answer, and if it will not work, we could try understand why.

Comment: Alex following your guidance, I have set up 'A' records. I wish I knew what to do next for 'NS' (probably it is my brain which is almost dead now). Just tell me what to enter in the 'NS' section of my DNS records. Should I leave it to 'ns1.myhost.arvixevps.com' ? I also tried entering CNAME as myhost.com => somevm.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com but it did not accept the value. Not sure why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111349/discussion-between-alex-belotserkovskiy-and-iwanttolearn).

Comment: Thanks Alex. You went out of the way to help me out. Not only did it solve my problem, you even explained me some concepts in a way I will never forget. Thanks again!